# How to override keras predict function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the predict function of Keras library but it is accepting the input as 4 dimensional array. However, my data generator is producing input as 2 dimensional array. To be more specific;

expected input ---> [n, channel, width, height]

my input ---> [n, width*height]

I need to handle this without changing my data generator. But, I couldn't figure out how can I override the predict function of Keras Library. Or is there any other way to handle this?

My data generator

```
def genData(n=1000, max_digs=2, width=60):
    capgen = ImageCaptcha()
    data = []
    target = []
    for i in range(n):
        x = np.random.randint(0, 10 ** max_digs)
        img = misc.imread(capgen.generate(str(x)))
        img = np.mean(img, axis=2)[:, :width]
        data.append(img.flatten())
        target.append(x)
    return np.array(data), np.array(target)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding keras predict function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086217/overriding-keras-predict-function)