# Overriding keras predict function

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have Keras model that accepts inputs which have 4D shapes as (n, height, width, channel).

However, my data generator is producing 2D arrays as(n, width*height). So, the predict function of Keras is expecting inputs as 4D. I have no chance to change the data generator because the model will be tested by someone else. So, is there a way to override the predict function of Keras.

My model structure

```
a = Input(shape=(width*height,))

d1 = 16  # depth of filter kernel each layer
d2 = 16
d3 = 64
d4 = 128
d5 = 256

drop_out = 0.25
patch_size = (3, 3)
k_size = (2, 2)

reshape = Reshape((height, width, 1))(a)

conv1 = Conv2D(filters=d1, kernel_size=patch_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(reshape)
conv1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=k_size, padding='same')(conv1)

conv2 = Convolution2D(filters=d2, kernel_size=patch_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(conv1)
conv2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=k_size, padding='same')(conv2)

conv3 = Convolution2D(filters=d3, kernel_size=patch_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(conv2)
conv3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=k_size, padding='same')(conv3)

conv4 = Convolution2D(filters=d4, kernel_size=patch_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(conv3)
conv4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=k_size, padding='same')(conv4)

conv5 = Convolution2D(filters=d5, kernel_size=patch_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(conv4)
conv5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=k_size, padding='same')(conv5)

x = Flatten()(conv5)

x = Dropout(drop_out)(x)
node = 32

x_1 = Dense(node, activation='relu')(x)  # connect the flatten layer to five classifier,each one comes to a digit.
x_2 = Dense(node, activation='relu')(x)
x_3 = Dense(node, activation='relu')(x)
x_4 = Dense(node, activation='relu')(x)
x_5 = Dense(node, activation='relu')(x)

d1 = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x_1)
d2 = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x_2)
d3 = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x_3)
d4 = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x_4)
d5 = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x_5)

outputs = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5]

model = Model(a, outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(raw_train_data, raw_train_target, batch_size=200, epochs=5, validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: Not sure if you can still override model.predict thought? Can you please share what you came up to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't override the predict, you simply add a `Reshape` layer at the beginning of your model.

With the functional API:

```
from keras.layers import *

inp = Input((width*heigth,))
first = Reshape((width,height,1))(inp)

..... other layers.....

model = Model(inp, outputFromTheLastLayer)
```

With a sequential model:

```
model = Sequential()    
model.add(Reshape((width,height,1), input_shape = (width*height,)))
model.add(otherlayers)
```

---

About the output shape.

Since you have 5 outputs, you need your target array to be a list of five arrays:

```
raw_train_target = [target1,target2,target3,target4,target5]
```

If you cannot do that, and `raw_train_target` is one single arary with the targets all following a sequence, you can try to use a concatenate layer at the end:

```
output = Concatenate()(outputs)
```

Comment: thank you. I think it will work. just one more question my raw data has the shape (n, width*height) so how should my inp looks like?

Comment: I tried what you suggest but because of my model has 5 outputs so it's giving me the error "The model expects 5target arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (100,)". I edit the post and add my model structure

Comment: I found the problem. it is complaining about my target arrays since I have a function which reshapes the target array. But, I should call it inside the predict function since as I sad, the model will be tested by someone else. However, predict function doesn't take target array as a parameter.

Comment: Just like you can add a reshape layer at the beginning, you can also add a reshape layer at the end. You can put those layers anywhere in the model.

Comment: Added something about the output to my answer.

Comment: @cnian. Can you please post what you did to your question?

Comment: @DanielMöller. Thank you. What this Reshape layer will exactly do please? It will reshape 4d matrix to 2d matrix?

Comment: @DanielMöller. Also, can we override predict any way with custom model please?

Comment: Why do you want to override predict? This will absolutely bring serious issues, especially when you haven't mastered the basics. A reshape layer changes the shape of the tensor, from whatever shape it has to the shape you define in the reshape layer, as long as it's a compatible shape (same number of elements). If I used `Reshape((width, height, 1))` it will reshape to a 4D tensor: `(hidden_batch_size, width, heigth, 1)`.

Comment: @DanielMöller. I got good understanding of basics (custom training, custom layers, etc.) I would like to override it to customize what output it will give (rank outputs for example).

Comment: @DanielMöller. Please have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490737/builing-custom-predict-function-for-model-in-keras

Comment: @DanielMöller. I would like to store index to actual output mapping in model property.