# Builing Custom Predict Function for Model in Keras

Tags: keras

I see Keras allows writing custom layers and training routines. But, for building a custom model in keras, we can build a class that will extend `keras.Model` class. We can customize the training step with gradient tape, but how about customizing the prediction function that is usually called `model.predict`?

```
class MiniInception(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
        super(MiniInception, self).__init__()

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False, **kwargs):
        # forward pass
        pass

    def build_graph(self, raw_shape): 
        pass
```

I would like to call our custom predict  `MiniInception.custom_predict()` not `MiniInception.predict()`? Can we do that please in keras?

**Edit**:

```
class MiniInception(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
        super(MiniInception, self).__init__()

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False, **kwargs):
        # forward pass
        pass

    def build_graph(self, raw_shape): 
        pass

    def custom_predict(self, whatever_inputs_you_want, **kwargs):
        #do whatever you like
 
        predict_results = self.predict(..., **kwargs)

        #do more

        return your_results
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a

```
def custom_predict(self, whatever_inputs_you_want, **kwargs):
    #do whatever you like
 
    predict_results = self.predict(..., **kwargs)

    #do more

    return your_results
```

Comment: I added your method to my class in the question above, is this the right way to do it please?

Comment: @Avv, yes.... a custom predict in your class.

Comment: How we can associate indices with output probabilities that should map back to the original input that gave these probabilities please? Can I Just create a map that will store input to predict function along with output probability? I am looking to rank input based on output probabilities.

Comment: @Avv, you're probably looking for an `argsort` function. Both numpy and tensorflow have one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007877/sort-arrays-rows-by-another-array-in-python

Comment: Thank you. I would like to sort in regard to inputs. So, if I just sort predicted probabilities, I will lose input order. This is why I would like to associate indices with output that correspond to input. What do you think please?

Comment: Argsort is your answer